# How can i get my characters feet to lie flat?

Tags: modeling

I used Cntrl A along the x axis to widen the feet and attempt to make them look flat.  Yet Cnrtl A (x) widened them along a diagonal.  Can anyone tell me what I did wrong in creating flat feet?  Thank you for any help you can offer.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the group of vertices that represent the shoe sole and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*.
[image]

Scale it along the Z axis (<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>) and press 0.
[image]

Add a loopcut to sharpen the edge. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, confirm the cut with <kbd>Left Mouse Click</kbd> and place the loopcut at the bottom of the sole.
[image]

Here's the result.
[image]

Comment: Wow!  i will give it a go. Thanks, this is awesome!